# how to randomly change the src of an iframe from a text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to change the src of an iframe randomly from a text file,so that when a user opens that iframe a different url is opened in iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function read() {
            var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            txtFile.open("GET", "https://9to5notes.com/new/add.txt",true);
            txtFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  
                    // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
                    if (txtFile.status === 200)
                    {  
                        var alltext=txtFile.responseText;
                        var linetext=txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
                        var delimeter = '^';
                        var text0= linetext[0];
                        var splitted = text0.split(delimeter);
                        console.log(splitted[1]);
                        $('#iframe1').attr('src', splitted[1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            txtFile.send(null)
        }
        $(function(){
            read();
        });
    </script>

    <iframe id="iframe1" src="" />
</body></html>
```

the text file looks like this
Site1^https://www.google.com/
Site2^https://www.facebook.com/

Comment: Your question is both unclear and too broad. Can you post something that you tried and it may have failed you? That way it would have at least shown some effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help those who first help themselves. You should go over the help area to familiarize yourself with what can and cannot be asked and what is expected of you https://stackoverflow.com/help - This will help improve your experience on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can not read a text file via JS, until you are using it in server side like node js.

Answer (score -1):

First read the text file with PHP

And store URL's into array of JavaScript

Then with random function place into iframe

Comment: If you are creating dynamic site then rather than PHP I suggest you to use node.js